# photodiode: Wavelength, intensity of xenon lamp

Tags: flash, photodiode

I am working on project but I am stuck at a point. I am developing a machine for medical purpose in that we send a white light(xenon lamp light) into the body and i have to catch the refracted(reflected) light and I am using a photodiode for the circuit which catches the reflected light but i couldnt find any relation between photodiode current and the wavelength of light(intensity). can some one help me how to relate current output of diode to the light intensity?

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: What does *wavelength of light(intensity)* means? Are you implying wavelength and intensity are the same, or is wavelength a function of intensity, or something else?

Comment: generally diode current is proportional to intensity, and independent (ish) (the more indepedenent, the better) of wavelength

Comment: You need to write a lot more about what you are attempting, and why. You exhibit a lot of ignorance about the physics of electromagnetic radiation and detectors by the why you write the question. So this means you need to write about the application in detail. It's possible this is a language barrier, though. Which means you need to write about the application in detail. Either way, same answer. "Medical purpose" is completely useless. So dig down and write about the specifics.

Comment: okay i am developing a jaundice detector machine, in that we send the white light in human skin and calculate the yellowness of the skin by measuring returned intensity of light(which obviously refracted by the bilirubin particles, bilirubin exessiveness is the cause for jaundice). So I have to get reflected light on a photodiode but i couldnt find any specific relation between light and current

Comment: In datasheet of photodiode it is only mentioned short circuit current and peak wavelength

Comment: @Neil_UK, that's not true at all. Typical photodiode responsivity curves are inversely proportional to the photon energy (because you get 1 carrier per photon), thus proportional to wavelength (up until the the photon energy drops below the bandgap and the responsivity drops to near 0.

Comment: @Abhijeet, please share the datasheet of the photodiode you are using.

Comment: @ThePhoton which bit of (ish) where you failing to get?

Comment: @Neil_UK, I don't consider "approximately proportional" and "independent-ish" to be synonyms.

Comment: @ThePhoton They're not. The meaning is that the output dependence on intensity can follow that over many orders of magnitude, with some approximation to linearity. The dependence on wavelength is much, much smaller, over the useful range. That may be a tautology, because they're only useful over the range for which their sensitivity ranges over less than an order of magnitude.

Comment: The discussion and answers _should_ be focused specifically on your application. Photodetectors have varying quantum efficiencies vs wavelength and, besides, they integrate everything they capture regardless of wavelength. In general, you can't determine the wavelength, only the current generated by all accepted wavelengths. This will likely be a problem.

Comment: "Rapid Prototyping of Neonatal Jaundice Detector Using Skin Optics Theory" is only one of many articles you should have absorbed (first one I found and read.) Your question should relate the best comprehensive view of all such articles, distilled into your own design concept which is then well-explained here. Don't expect engineers to know this stuff. They might. But **_you_** need to be the expert in this area. Designers here can help with the electronics design. But in general, not with an effective use directed at such a specific application area without specific requirements listed.

Comment: For example: Kudavalley et al is cited to have used two LED wavelengths, 455 nm and 575 nm, for bilrubin detection; while Mansor et all proposed a digital camera and color detection. There are many others, too. You may also need a means and plan by which to calibrate such a system, even assuming you have a viable method that is robust across various individual variations. All this may need to be digested so that you can divide your project into specific sub-questions to be asked here, each carefully bounded with appropriate knowledge and details.

Comment: Kudavalley's paper notes a problem with LEDs/reflectance at those wavelengths, as adults also include interfering triglycerides and carotenes. So is this a neonatal thing? Or for anyone of any age? The problem doesn't appear to be entirely as trivial as just "using a photodiode," from what I've read so far. In addition to confounding problems, Kudavalley for example also required narrow band filtering prior to the detector. (Thin films.) I think you need to carefully consider your design and the question should reflect that care. (I'm not impressed with the research I've seen so far, either.)

Answer (score 2):

The spectral repsonse of a photodiode depends mainly on the semiconductor material it's made of.

For example, a typical silicon photodiode has a response like this:

[image]

The curve increases with wavelength because each incoming photon generates no more than one electron-hole carrier pair to produce current. So as the photon energy falls, you get more current per watt of incoming optical power.

At about 1000 nm, the curve drops dramatically because longer-wavelength photons don't have enough energy to excite an electron across the band gap (about 1.1 eV for silicon). By choosing a different semiconductor material, you can extend this long-wavelength limit, but that is probably not important for your visible-wavelength application.

You may also find some devices have a short-wavelength limit as well, for example caused when the absoption depth becomes longer than the active region of the device.

The response curve can also be changed by adding thin-film coatings to the surface of the photodetector, often called anti-reflection or AR coatings. These will improve the response at some wavelengths by reducing the reflection at the air-semiconductor boundary, but generally reduce the response at other wavelengths.

If you are, for example, trying to do a differential absorption measurement, you'll want to know the actual response of your particular devices, either by measuring it or by buying from a trustworthy vendor who provides reasonable datasheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use a well-characterized photodiode from a manufacturer with a good reputation. Most photodiodes are silicon-based, and they yield most current for infrared wavelengths. Shorter wavelengths (toward red, green, blue) yield less current. However, optical filters are sometimes added to modify wavelength response. This is often done in an attempt to reduced the long-wavelength sensitivity.
Shown are two wavelength responses for two silicon photodiodes. The first is a PIN photodiode, the second combines three photodiode responses to show how filters affect wavelength response. Also shown is the quantum efficiency limit to sensitivity.
Note also that at the infrared end, sensitivity can be affected by temperature, above and beyond the dark-current temperature limit.
[image: PIN S1223 Hammamatsu][image: various Si Hamamatsu]